# BitmapSource as source to Image Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmapimage

I have this

```
BitmapSource  source = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

How I can use it to apply as **source** for `WPF Image` somehow?

Please provide code sample.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BitmapSource` derives from `ImageSource`, so you can assign it directly to the `Source` property of an `Image`.